# Con.open error ASP.NET in Godaddy Plesk Hosting

Tags: asp.net, connection

I am struggling with my new website which I recently uploaded on Godaddy server.
Con.open() is the line which is causing error : The wait operation timed out

My Code: file.aspx.cs

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=databaseserverurl;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=something;Password=something;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
   con.Open();
}

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from mytable";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**For MySQL**

You should use MySqlConnection, not SqlConnection.

**For SQL Server**

Most likely your `databaseserverurl` is wrong. Make sure your connection string corresponds to the one you have in the control panel. See https://de.godaddy.com/help/find-your-connection-strings-3323.

To ensure, open Sql Server Management Tool (or your favorite sql tool) and login your db with same server, user and password.

Comment: I have already gone through the procedure listed in the url provided.
**From your list of databases, click Actions next to the database you want to use, and then click Details.** 
There is no actions button next to my database, there is only _webadmin_ and _copy_ option.

Comment: The page where you see that information may vary depends on your account - shared/dedicated, server location and time when you got that account. In any case it should be somewhere where you create your db. How databaseserverurl looks like? Did you try to login via SSMS (Sql Server Management Tool)?

Comment: yes @smirnov I tried logging through Navicat Lite and the credentials are working fine over there.

Comment: We're talking about sql server database, not mysql, right? If true, try to change it as `Data Source=whsql-v16.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net; Initial Catalog=DB_138988; User ID=trialdb; Password='your password';` being without `Network Library=DBMSSOCN;` which is server specific (not sure how exactly it is configured for your db server).

Comment: I removed the network library as you directed and now it is showing:
**The network path was not found**

Comment: Again, how the databaseserverurl looks like? I believe, it's a shared sql server - so, it will be no problem if you share its name here.

Comment: Where did you get that IP from? Typically goddady provides a DNS CNAME  such as whsql-v16.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net or DsYxwq9Jad.db.12100875.hostedresource.com because they could move the database or its server any time to a new server with a new IP. It could be also that you need to specify a named instance, e.g. <address>\namedinstance. Anyway, "The network path was not found" is clearly saying that the database under given IP cannot be found. You either need to find the correct db address in the hosting panel or contact your support at godaddy.

Comment: If the url is incorrect that how I was able to connect it successfully, using Navicat Lite under MySQL

Comment: MySQL? Didn't I ask you `We're talking about sql server database, not mysql, right?` You are using db classes for SQL Server, not MySql. SqlConnection is for SQL Server, you need MySqlConnection for MySql

Comment: It seems I need to contact the Godaddy Support team since changing the conn string also isn't working out for me. I just accessed the database (MySQL) using Navicat and then changed the conn string but the same issue "The network path was not found"

Comment: It will not work, because you use db classes for sql server. So, .net tries to connect sql server, which does not exist.